# Magento 2 : How to save data in database

Tags: magento2, database, save

I want to save some data in to custom table.When I use static value to save data then it is going good but If I try to use dynamic data or used any calculation in between then It is going in infinite loop.

Please have look :

```
namespace Namespace\Module\Model;
use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;
class Test extends AbstractModel
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Namespace\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Test');
    }
    public function aftersave()
    {
        $data = $this->_objectManager->get('Namespace\Module\Model\Test')->load(10);     
       /* I also try
       $data = $this->_objectManager->create('Namespace\Module\Model\Test')->load(10);  */
       $this->customValues($data);
    } 
    public function customValues($data)
    {
         $date = new \Zend_Date('2016-09-12', self::DB_DATE_FORMAT);
         $data->setDate($date);
         $data->save(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: you are calling same save function in after save which goes infinite

Comment: first it save it call after save and in after save you are calling save function again

Comment: @MineshPatel Yes but as I said if I use fixed value then issue is not generating.

Comment: seems impossible

Comment: if you are saving data using model it should go in infinite for every data

Answer (score 2):

you are going into an infinite loop because the method `aftersave` is a callback for the `save` method and it is executed (as the name says) after the save is done.
So you are doing this:

save -> aftersave -> customValues-> save -> aftersave ,.... and so on.

You should never call `save` in a save callback.

Comment: @maris If I set predefine value like :   $data->setDate('2016-05-17');       $data->save();  Then it is working fine. :(